# Tab and keyboard enter ends up entering the logic twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following where on click, a component is supposed to toggle between add

and delete for a name from a list which is in useState.

This works perfectly fine if I mouse click it.

But if I were to tab click to reach a components and click enter (for accessibility), I end up entering the logic twice.

For example it is meant to toggle to add.

So first time it comes in to the function, I enter the **else** block and updates list since list

doesn't have that name. That should be it. No further operations.

But instead, it comes in again. Since it came again, this time it sees that it exists thus ends up entering the **if** block removing it.

So from UI perspective it looks like nothing happened. Since it toggles twice every time.

Question is why, why is it all fine when I mouse click, but tab and enter click causes this issue?

Could I get some advice / solutions for this please. Thanks.

```
const Component = ({ids}) => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(ids);
  const [selectedCount, setSelectedCount] = React.useState(ids.length);

  // this is the function mentioned above. when I click one of the Selector components below,
  // it should just go into an if, or an else. Instead it is entering both as mentioned.
  // As if I double clicked. But I didn't. When I tab nothing happens, and only get here
  // when I press Enter. So one single Enter. (So I'd think same as 1 single mouse click which works fine?)
  const selectData = (id) => {
    if (selected.includes(id)) {
      setSelected(selected.filter(
        dataId => dataId !== id));
      setSelectedCount(selectedCount - 1);
    } else {
      setSelected(dataIds => [...dataIds, id]);
      setSelectedCount(selectedCount + 1);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Selector
        onSelect={() => {
          selectData('id one');
        }}
      />
      <Selector
        onSelect={() => {
          selectData('id two');
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

This is the Selector component which is an external typescript file. 
(Removed most of the styling to keep it small)

```
interface Props {
  data: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    image: {
      href: string;
      alt: string;
    };
  };
  $selected?: boolean;
  $disabled?: boolean;
  $layout?: "vertical" | "horizontal";
  onSelect?: (id: string) => void;
}

const Selector = ({
  data: { id, title, image },
  $selected,
  $disabled,
  $layout,
  onSelect
}: Props) => {
  const [background, setBackground] = React.useState(undefined);

  const onClick = () => {
    if (!$disabled && onSelect) {
      onSelect(id);
    }
  };

  const isHorizontal = $layout === "horizontal";
  const isVertical = $layout === "vertical";

  return (
    <Element
      Component="button"
      onClick={onClick}
      onKeyPress={onClick}
      type="button"
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        if (!$disabled && !$selected) {
          setBackground(Color.Gray01);
        }
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setBackground(undefined);
      }}
    >
      {$selected && (
        <Element
          Component="button"
          type="button"
          onClick={onClick}
          onKeyPress={onClick}
        >
        </Element>
      )}
    </Element>
  );
};

export default Selector;
```

Comment: what is the `Selector` component ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli It is an external typescript file. Added it to the question for reference. Unlikely for me to make changes to it though. Looking to achieve a fix within my Component. Thanks.

Comment: Cant really know, without seeing a working example we can fiddle with, but the `Selector` component seems to be nesting `button` elements and that is invalid.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Is there anyway I could have a work around to not enter twice, like a flag or something on my end to stop the second entry. Doesn't seem feasible since the flag not gonna know when to reset. Just wondering.

Comment: If you could make a minimal reproducible example at https://codesandbox.io/s/new i could have a look